# How to not send a cookie to a subdomain

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, cookies, cdn

How can I stop sending cookie to only specific subdomain?

I have hosted images and assets in CDN. Its urls are

1. images.website.com
2. assets.website.com

I provide subdomains to all registered users, suppose

1. user1.website.com
2. user2.website.com
3. and so on..

I need cookies to be sent in all the subdomain so that if I navigate from user1.website.com to user2.website.com I must be looged in. 
But I dont want cookies to be sent to CDN url.

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Other than putting the CDN and Assets server under completely different domains I don't think this is possible.

Comment: When you give somebody a biscuit it is their choice who eats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to do so :(